# Is there a way to partially cluster data which contains clusters but does not wholly consist of clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I have some 2D data (x,y) and I need to identify where there are many data points all close to each other in the x direction. There are 3 obvious clusters where all the x points are close together and the rest of the data does not fall into them. I was going to use a k-means clustering algorithm but that seems to be for clustering ALL of the data whereas I just want to label the 3 clusters data in the data that are obviously clusters and label the rest as normal data.

The data is in separate csv files which I process and then read into one big dataframe. So far while processing the data, I have filtered out files where processed data exceeds a certain length but this obviously means that sometimes part of the cluster is left out of the file or normal data is left out.

Comment: Do you have a rough guess on how much "clustered" vs "standard" data there is? Does the clustered data make up the majority, or is there mostly standard data with only a little bit clustered? If the majority is clustered, then probably any clustering algorithms that are robust to noise would be fine.

Comment: There are about 300 standard points and around 300 points in each cluster?

Comment: Great! As long as the outliers don't dominate the data, then you should be good with any robust clustering algorithms, including DBSCAN as the selected answer states.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!

Comment: You could have done a little bit of research yourself... Such as checking the list of clustering algorithms in sklearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) which allows classification of points as "noise", and seems to be what you're after.  There's a hierarchical version of this affiliated with the scikit project known as [`hdbscan`](https://pypi.org/project/hdbscan/)

Google finds are various [documents](https://www.datascience.com/blog/k-means-alternatives) describing alternatives to k-means clustering. 
 The `hdbscan` docs also have a good description of [comparing alternatives](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html).

Comment: the [hdbscan paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07321.pdf) has them clustering 200k points in <10 seconds (figure 4)